# Brackets in regular expressions

Tags: jquery, regex

```
<div class="text">[abc] [abc]</div>
<div class="text">foo</div>
<div class="text">bar</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var match = '[abc]';
$('div.text:contains(' + match + ')').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(match, 'xyz'));
});
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/WM6wG/6/

Currently, this works, but does not seem to match any additional instances of [abc]. I was told to use regex global in this instance, but upon using `new RegExp(match, 'g');` it would reiterate over each character instead of each instance of `[abc]`

How can I adjust this so all instances of `[abc]` turn into `xyz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `RegExp` approach (so you can use `g`), but change your string to `'\\[abc\\]'`.

`[]` are special characters in regex, so you need to escape them. (Note that you need to also escape the backslashes for the string literal.)

You can also use a regex literal in place of `new RegExp(...)`, like this: `/\[abc\]/g`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to double-escape `\\` special characters when you build a regex as a string. You can use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript) or simply use a literal regex:

```
$(this).text().replace(/\[abc\]/g, 'xyz')
```